# digiKam 7.4.0 can't change wallpaper - ubuntu 21.10

Tags: desktop-background, digikam

**digiKam** won’t let me set any images for wallpaper! How should I do that?

> Cannot change wallpaper image from current desktop with
> file:///mnt/A4DCE4A0DCE46DCC/----/Pictures/----/----.jpeg
>
> Error: The name org.kde.plasmashell was not provided by any .service
> files

[image]

system info:

[image]

I installed it from Snap Store.

[image]

edit:

in `/home` directory:

[image]

didn't worked!

Comment: Is this a Snap package?

Comment: Yes it is a Snap package.

Comment: Snap packages are generally limited to accessing resources in your home directory. In order to use `----.jpeg` as a wallpaper, you'll need to either mount the external device as a directory in your `/home`, or you'll need to copy those files to a location in your `/home` ...